# Proof that Beta-function $B(m,n)$ = $\frac{n-1}{m}B(m+1,n-1)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, beta-function

When m and n are positive integers.

It probably has to do with the incomplete Beta-function $B_{sin^2(x)}(m,n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, we have
$$
B(m,n)=\int_0^1x^{m-1}(1-x)^{n-1}dx, \qquad n,\,m=1,2,\cdots.
$$
If we integrate by parts, we get

> $$
> \begin{align}
> B(m,n)=\int_0^1x^{m-1}(1-x)^{n-1}dx
> &=\left. \frac{x^m}m(1-x)^{n-1}\right|_0^1+\frac{n-1}m\int_0^1x^m(1-x)^{n-2}dx\\\\
> &=0+\frac{n-1}mB(m+1,n-1)\\\\
> &=\frac{n-1}mB(m+1,n-1)\qquad m\geq1,\,n\geq2,
> \end{align}
> $$

as announced.

Comment: Ooooooooh right. I was missing the $|_0^1$ . All clear now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Gloomy You are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

This is easily demonstrated using the integral definition of the Beta-function and then integrating by parts.

Comment: Can you get me started? I'm trying, but can't figure it out.
What do you choose as u and v'?

Comment: You should look at the function you are finishing with. The $x^{m-1}$ is reduced to $x^{m-2}$, so you should be differentiating to find that, so you should use $u=x^{m-1}, \, v'=(1-x)^{n-1}$